# How to recreate Orange3 scatter plot option "color regions" in pyqtgraph

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot, pyqtgraph, orange

I made a plot I really like in Orange3.  It looks like this:
[image: Scatter Plot with color gradient background]

I would like to recreate it outside of Orange3 (I want to generate it in realtime inside a game based on sprite movement)

I dug into the orange code enough to find that it is using pyqtgraph to produce the plot.  Further, I think the background shading comes from this:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

from AnyQt.QtCore import QRectF
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ImageItem import ImageItem


# load the C++ library; The _grid_density is build and distributed as a
# python extension but does not export any python objects (apart from PyInit),
from . import _grid_density
lib = ctypes.pydll.LoadLibrary(_grid_density.__file__)


# compute the color/class density image
def class_density_image(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, resolution, x_data, y_data, rgb_data):
    x_sz = (max_x-min_x)/(resolution-1)
    y_sz = (max_y-min_y)/(resolution-1)
    x_grid = [min_x+i*x_sz for i in range(resolution)]
    y_grid = [min_y+i*y_sz for i in range(resolution)]
    n_points = len(x_data)
    sample = range(n_points)
    if n_points > 1000:
        sample = grid_sample(x_data, y_data, 1000)
    x_data_norm = (np.array(x_data)-min_x)/(max_x-min_x)
    y_data_norm = (np.array(y_data)-min_y)/(max_y-min_y)
    x_grid_norm = (np.array(x_grid)-min_x)/(max_x-min_x)
    y_grid_norm = (np.array(y_grid)-min_y)/(max_y-min_y)
    img = compute_density(x_grid_norm, y_grid_norm,
                          x_data_norm[sample], y_data_norm[sample], np.array(rgb_data)[sample])
    density_img = ImageItem(img.astype(np.uint8), autoLevels=False)
    density_img.setRect(QRectF(min_x-x_sz/2, min_y-y_sz/2,
                               max_x-min_x+x_sz, max_y-min_y+y_sz))
    density_img.setZValue(-1)
    return density_img
```

I am new to this, but am I correct in thinking that this:

```
    # load the C++ library; The _grid_density is build and distributed as a
    # python extension but does not export any python objects (apart from PyInit),
    from . import _grid_density
    lib = ctypes.pydll.LoadLibrary(_grid_density.__file__)
```

means that there I am not going to be able to implement this in a packageable pure python solution?  If so, do any of the plotting libraries (seaborn, bokeh, etc) have the ability to make a plot like this one?